# How do you set up a foreign key in SQL Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure, foreign-keys, azure-sql-database

How do you set up a foreign key in SQL Azure?

I have a database now on the Azure system.

The tables in the database have an intended use such that there is one main, logically centralized table and then there are a number of tables which each describe some column in the main table.  For example, if I have an age classification column in the main table, I might have a separate table which lists some categories of the age classification (as a string) and some associated index.  Then the index from the age classification table would be used as a reference in the main table.

Is this what a foreign key is?  Is there some way in SQL Azure to make the association between these indexes?

Answer (score 9):

yep - that's what a foreign key is.

Perhaps the easiest way is using t-sql in a SSMS query window

```
alter table MyTable
add constraint MyTable_MyColumn_FK FOREIGN KEY ( MyColumn ) REFERENCES MyOtherTable(MyOtherIDColumn)
```

(from: [How do I create a foreign key in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48772/how-do-i-create-a-foreign-key-in-sql-server))

SQL Azure is different from other SQL Servers in some respects, but not in terms of this simple command.

I found the [SQL Azure Migration Wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/)  invaluable for converting 'normal' sql to Azure SQL.

Comment: Another nice way is to first have the database up and running locally and then script it out with the settings specifically for SQL Azure to make sure it runs in the cloud. All from within SSMS.