# How to validate user's access to specific rows in a SQL table?

Tags: sql, t-sql, authentication, azure-sql-database, azure-api-apps

I'm working on a project and I'm new to both web apps and SQL, so bear with me. I'm building an API and I want to make sure that my users only have access to certain rows in a specific table that have a foreign key to their customer id in another table, but have to be validated by user id in another table. (A single Customer has multiple Users and owns multiple Assets. For right now, all of the Customer's Users can access any Asset, but no Customers share an Asset or User.) The way I can think to do this is to do

```
SELECT * FROM [Asset] WHERE Id=@AssetId AND CustomerId=(SELECT CustomerId FROM [User] WHERE UserId=@UserId);
```

This is great, but with many entries in the Asset and User tables, this query could take up a ton of time. This is bad since every request made to my API that needs the Asset data should be doing this check. I could set up an index, and in fact UserId is a Secondary Key in User because it's a unique identifier from the auth provider, but I'm not sure if I should add an index for CustomerId in Asset. The Asset table should grow relatively slowly compared to some other tables (have a messaging record table for auditing purposes), but I'm not sure if that's the right answer, or if there's some simpler answer that's more optimized. Or is this kind of query so fast at scale that I have nothing to worry about?

Comment: If your tables are large enough, you should benefit from indexes on CustomerId to speed up the join between the two tables, and on UserId to speed up the lookup. Also, have you considered using the new Row-Level Security feature on Azure SQL Database? It is designed to simplify these kinds of queries by applying the access logic for you automatically. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn765131.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular case, it looks like the perfect context to build a [junction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) table between the User table and the Asset table. Both field together will become the primary key. Individually, AssetId and UserId will be [foreign keys.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384966/how-do-you-set-up-a-foreign-key-in-sql-azure)

Let's say the junction table is called AssetUser.

**Foreign keys** :

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_AssetUser_User] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [User]([UserId])

CONSTRAINT [FK_AssetUser_Asset] FOREIGN KEY ([AssetId]) REFERENCES [Asset]([AssetId])
```

**Primary key** :

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_AssetUser] PRIMARY KEY([AssetId], [UserId]));
```

You shouldn't worry about scale too much unless you are going to have ALOT of data and/or the performance is critical in your application. If so, you have the option to use [hadoop](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/hdinsight/) or to migrate to a NoSQL database.

Comment: Use foreign keys how? I can't have a foreign key for User in Asset because multiple Users have access to the same Assets, but both have foreign keys for Customer.

Comment: Oh, okay, I already set up UserId as a secondary key, so search is fast in User. If I set up this junction table, I could hypothetically allow Customers to individually give access to individual Assets to individual Users in their organization.

Comment: Yes, you will get more flexibility and it will be faster !

Comment: So my query to access a particular Asset with a particular UserId would look like this?

`SELECT * FROM [Asset] WHERE Id=(SELECT AssetId FROM [AssetUser] WHERE AssetId=@AssetId AND UserId=@UserId);`

Comment: Yes, this is how it would look like

Comment: To get all ot the User assets you could change your query in the above comment ... WHERE Id IN (...)

Comment: Oh, that's nifty. I needed that procedure too. It would be impossible to do otherwise. I'd have to give all of the Customer's Assets to all of their Users. Something like `SELECT * FROM [Asset] WHERE CustomerId=(SELECT CustomerId FROM [User] WHERE UserId=@UserId);` Great. So is there any special sauce I need to make the junction indexed by both AssetId and UserId, or can just add an index for UserId like this? `CONSTRAINT [FK_AssetUser_User] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [User]([UserId])`