# I want to refrence the elements of one table from another table by using primary keys of the table

Tags: sql-server, jstl

i have two tables one is tblstate with one stateid as primary key and second statename name.And have another table as tbldistrict with feild districtid(primary key),districtname,stateid.How to link specific stateid from tblstate into column stateid of tbldistrict to take the values of that stateid of tblstate?

Now what i want is that if i have one statename with many district then how i will use this command in jsp(jstl) for autofill option?

stuck plz reply

Comment: Please post sample data for the tables.  That will greatly help responders.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask here is two distinct issues.

For the first one, you need a foreign key. Here is [how to do with SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48772/how-do-i-create-a-foreign-key-in-sql-server).

For the second one, you need to give us more details about what you want to achieve, and a sample code.