# VB.Net Create a table programatically with foreign key

Tags: sql, vb.net, t-sql

I'm trying to create a table programmatically via VB.Net and two of the columns should have a primary key. I have the following T-SQL code and I basically need to translate it to SQL so I can execute it programmatically via vb.net :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders] 
(
    [OrderID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [FoodID]  INT NOT NULL,
    [PriceID] INT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([OrderID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Orders_Customer] 
       FOREIGN KEY ([FoodID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([FoodID])
)
```

This is what I currently have for my vb.net sql code:

```
 CREATE TABLE customer(OrderID INT NOT NULL,FoodID INT NOT NULL ,PriceID INT NOT NULL
```

Now I'm not sure how to declare the primary key and how to declare the foreign keys. Also if someone would show an example on how to declare a composite key I would also be grateful (ie. `OrderID` and `FoodID` both primary keys). Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried google?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a foreign key in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48772/how-do-i-create-a-foreign-key-in-sql-server)

Comment: you can go into table designer, design it and then get DDL by scripting create to new window. Copy that into vb.net string. What is your problem here?