# C# insert into details table with master details id

Tags: c#

I am really new to C# and I have searched all over but I didn't find answer to problem.

in my application I have a table for example (`employee details`) second table is `leaves`.

what I want is to link `employee details` tables primary key to `leaves` table.

> employee can have many leaves

So when I insert `leaves` record for `employee` it should store with `employee details` table id and when I search in `leaves` form with `emid` it shows all his `leaves` in datagridview.

**employee details** table

```
emid
empno
emname
emjoindate
emmobile
emaddress
```

**leaves** table

```
leaveid
emid
leavestartdate
leaveenddate

private void Save()
        {
                con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
                con.Open();
                string cb = "insert into leaves(leavestartdate,leaveenddate,notes) VALUES (@d1,@d2,@d3)";


                cmd = new SqlCommand(cb);

                cmd.Connection = con;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d1", SqlDbType.Date, 31, "leavestartdate"));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d2", SqlDbType.Date, 31, "leaveenddate"));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d3", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 500, "notes"));

                cmd.Parameters["@d1"].Value = txtstartdate.Text.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters["@d2"].Value = txtenddate.Text.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters["@d3"].Value = txtnotes.Text.Trim();
                con.Close();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a foreign key in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48772/how-do-i-create-a-foreign-key-in-sql-server)

Comment: Its just foreign key you need.

Comment: You need to use employee record id when you inserting new leave record.  So in your code you need to add one more parameter for `emid` field and set it to emplayee.emid value

Comment: can you please edit my code to make it better understandable for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `emid` parameter to `insert query.`

```
string cb = "insert into leaves(emid,leavestartdate,leaveenddate,notes) VALUES (@emid,@d1,@d2,@d3)";
```

and then set value of parameter `@emid`

then you can select `leaves` of any `emid` like this

```
string cb = "select * from leaves where emid = @emid";
```

**EDIT:** To get `emname` and `emmobile` from `employee details` table you can use this query

```
SELECT L.*, ED.emname , EM.emmobile 
FROM leaves L INNER JOIN
employee_details ED ON L.emid = ED.emid
WHERE L.emid = @emid
```

Comment: how do i get employee leaves record in datagridview on search

Comment: is it possible if i search emid from leaves it shows employee name and mobile number from employee details table in to textbox?

Comment: After inserting emid to both tables, you will have key to connect records. I will edit my post, and that way you can get detailed data

Answer (score 1):

have you ever tried using select query. Because from select query also we can do this.

Comment: i am unable to understand how to use two tables for insert data