# MySQL Issues With Syntax - Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey just wondering if someone could potentially help me with figure out how i could fix my MySQL work.

The issue appears to be within the 3rd table (tblRoster) as all other tables execute just fine on their own, i am unsure if it is an issue with the Foreign key formatting or something else, sorry i am still pretty new to this

```
CREATE TABLE tblStaff(
    StaffID INT(10) NOT NULL,
    FirstName VARCHAR(20),
    LastName VARCHAR(25),
    TeamLeader BOOLEAN,
    HourlyRate DECIMAL(2,2),
    PRIMARY KEY(StaffID)
);


CREATE TABLE tblEvent(
    EventID INT(10) NOT NULL,
    EDate DATE,
    ETime TIME,
    PRIMARY KEY(EventID)
);

CREATE TABLE tblRoster(
    RosterID INT(10) NOT NULL,
    Station VARCHAR(15),
    FOREIGN KEY(tblStaff.StaffID),
    FOREIGN KEY(tblEvent.EventID),
    PRIMARY KEY(RosterID)
);
```

Comment: Please Search Properly before posting any question. This question is already asked by someone [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48772/how-do-i-create-a-foreign-key-in-sql-server/48778]

Answer (score 1):

The foreign key declarations needs a `references` clause.  And the columns need to be declared:

```
CREATE TABLE tblRoster (
    RosterID INT(10) NOT NULL,
    Station VARCHAR(15),
    StaffID INT,
    EventID INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (StaffID) REFERENCES tblStaff(StaffID),
    FOREIGN KEY (EventID) REFERENCES tblEvent(EventID),
    PRIMARY KEY(RosterID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defile staffid and eventid as well in the create statement when you are referencing the foreign key. And roosterid should be your primary key

```
CREATE TABLE tblRoster(
RosterID INT(10) NOT NULL,
Station VARCHAR(15),
StaffID INT,
EventID INT,
FOREIGN KEY (StaffID) REFERENCES tblStaff(StaffID),
FOREIGN KEY (EventID) REFERENCES tblEvent(EventID),
PRIMARY KEY(RosterID) 
);
```

Comment: that is not working in mysql workbench and gives an error

Comment: My bad forgot to provide, reference table. Try now, edited the query

Comment: the INT(10) gives a deprecation warning, but now your answer is at least correct

Comment: Integer is default data type, i have provided length by mistake. Rectified the query, try now